# How do I set up a Linux system with multiple IP6 addresses?

Tags: linux, ipv6, ip-address

I'm interested in setting up a Linux machine with several IP6 addresses. How do I do this?

Also, is there a theoretical and/or practical limitation on how many addresses a machine can have?

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to achieve, why you need multiple addresses? It could affect the answer, there is undoubtedly more than one way to do it, and the choice of method will be affected by what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

The general but legacy way on Debian is to use "virtual" ethernet devices:

`$sudo ifconfig eth0:0`

gives me:

```
eth0:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Which is the first "virtual" device of your first real (physical) device.

Now check `/etc/network/interfaces` (here on Debian, may be different on other distri).

With IPv4 it would go like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Just a start. :-) Now I don't know much about IPv6.

For 2nd question, I tried this:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0:99999999999999999999999999999999999
eth0:9999999999: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 44:8a:5b:84:71:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
$
```

So 9999999999 seems to be the limit?

Comment: [That is the old way of doing things on Debian.](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Legacy_method)  The new way works somewhat differently and your deductions do not apply to it.

Comment: Yes, it is. Then also I should look around for the new way.